# Inequality between two random walks if comparison of moment of step is known

Tags: probability, inequality, random-walk, expected-value

Let $B_i =\pm 1$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v. with probability $1/2$ each.
Let $X_i \geq 0$ be i.i.d. r.v.'s, and independent to $B_i$'s.
Let $Y_i \geq 0$ be i.i.d. r.v.'s, and independent to $B_i$'s.
Suppose, for $q=1,2,3,\dotsc$,
$$\mathbb{E} (X_i^q) \leq \mathbb{E} (Y_i^q) <\infty$$
Define
$$\tilde{X}_N :=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i B_i$$
$$\tilde{Y}_N :=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i B_i$$
Prove or disprove: for $q=1,2,3,\dotsc$,
$$\mathbb{E} (|\tilde{X}_N|^q) \leq \mathbb{E} (|\tilde{Y}_N|^q)?$$
Instinct: It seems very plausible to be true.
Since each step is symmetric, the larger the step is, the larger the total distance is, and $x^q$ (which is convex) seems even to make the difference larger.
However, I do not know how to break the absolute value of $|\tilde{X}_N|^q$.
We can't use Jensen inequality "on both sides" (which does not make sense).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is true for all even $q=2,4,\ldots$. You can just expand the sums and find that the inequality holds term by term using your assumption. The case of odd $q$ is harder, though I suspect it still holds. One idea: try the so-called "hybrid" method, where you transform $\tilde{X}_N$ to $\tilde{Y}_N$ by replacing the $X_i$ by $Y_i$ one at a time. If the inequality holds at each step, then you can string them together to get the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, the even cases are pretty obvious, but I made no progress in the odd cases.

Comment: @JasonGaitonde I am thinking that, for odd $q$, I expand $|\sum_i X_i B_i|^q =[(\sum_i X_i B_i)^{2q} ]^{1/2}$ by generalized multinomial theorem to make them a infinite sum of terms with all-integer powers. However, convergence is a concern.

Comment: I was thinking of that but ran into some issues with ambiguous signs making them harder to compare. I think the statement is true in a limiting sense as $N\to \infty$ via the Central Limit Theorem, but what's weird is it seems to only depend on the second moment inequality, not all of them (other than that they are finite). Really interesting problem.